# QApplication::sendEvent() to QListView crashes app

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

When sending a event via QApplication::sendEvent() to a QListView my app crashes.

```
void MyQWidget::keyPressEvent(QKeyEvent * event)
{
    if (event->key() == Qt::Key_Up || event->key() == Qt::Key_Down) {
        QApplication::sendEvent(this->view,event);  // this.view being the QListView
    }

    QWidget::keyPressEvent(event);
}
```

Anyone know the cause?

Comment: Are you sure your `QListView` is initialized?

Comment: It is: `this->view = new QListView(this);`, but the model is empty.